# ionic how to call function when specific view load?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

i need to show /hide buttons at specific ion view
and this buttons appearance depend on function 
as my sample:

```
 .controller('IntroCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {

$scope.showalbums=false;
$scope.showalbums_new=true;
 checkfolders();

if(hasalbums==1)
{
    $scope.showalbums=true;
$scope.showalbums_new=false;
}
```

and in html page:

```
 <i class="ion-images font-ion margin-right-8" ng-click="myAlbums()" ng-show="showalbums"></i>

        <button class="button button-positive button-clear no-animation"
         ng-click="showAlert2()" ng-if="slideIndex == 2" ng-show="showalbums_new" >
```

and my method in js:

```
var hasalbums=0;
    function checkfolders()
    {

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function(fileSystem){ // success get file system

                directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
                if( !directoryEntry.isDirectory ) {
        hasalbums=0;
        }

        currentDir = directoryEntry; // set current directory

        directoryEntry.getParent(function(par){ // success get parent
            parentDir = par; // set parent directory

        }, function(error){ // error get parent
            hasalbums=0;
        });

        var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
        directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){


            alert(hasalbums);
            if(entries.length>0)
            {

                hasalbums=1;
            }else{
                hasalbums=0;
            }

        }, function(error){
            hasalbums=0;
        });

            }, function(evt){ // error get file system
                hasalbums=0;
            }
        );
        alert(hasalbums);
    }
```

but method not called and can't show/hide buttons as i need 
while this function is working correctly

Comment: Are you sure that your controller is being called? Could you perhaps show some of your routing? (Usually found in app.js in Ionic apps) And could you also share what you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: yes controller was called

Comment: I am asking whether you are sure that your controller is working. For example, are you able to access `$scope.showalbums` in your view?

Answer (score 2):

In Ionic, controllers normally only load once. So we need to use `ionic's` lifecycle events to trigger some logic in your controller everytime you arrive at this view. Example:

```
.controller('IntroCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function () {
    checkfolders();
  });
```

Now your `checkfolders()` method will be executed everytime you arrive at this view, after your content has `loaded`. Refer this for other lifecycle events in `ionic`: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Comment: $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function () {
    checkfolders();
  });] not working

Comment: What is meant by `not working` ? Is the function executed after your view is loaded? Try adding a console.log and check

Comment: in emulator it alert once but when i go to same view it not alert

Comment: This is the wrong event, it should be `$ionicView.beforeEnter` if you want it to fire every time the view opens.